# Assistance in proving or disproving the existence of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, systems-of-equations

Given a matrix of $12$ non-negative integer elements (out of which at most only a single be of the value $0$), for comfortability arranged as $3$ lines with $4$ columns, I would like to prove or disprove the existence of a special property like matrix.
Denote:
$$  \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 \\
a_9 & a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm looking for a matrix such that, if we denote $s=a_1 +... + a_{12}$, we have:

1. $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4 = \frac{s}{3}$
2. $a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8 = \frac{s}{3}$
3. $a_9+a_{10}+a_{11}+a_{12} = \frac{s}{3}$
4. $a_1+a_2+a_5+a_9 = \frac{s}{3}$
5. $a_3+a_6+a_{10}+a_{11} = \frac{s}{3}$
6. $a_4+a_7+a_8+a_{12} = \frac{s}{3}$

Additionally, I want these to be the only possible ways one can reach (precisely) $\frac{s}{3}$ by using $4$ elements, so matrices like:

$$  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

don't work for me.

Before tackling this problem, I tackled a similiar one in which I require another division to give me $\frac{s}{3}$, that is (additionally to equations $1$ to $6$):

1. $a_1+a_3+a_7+a_{12} = \frac{s}{3}$
2. $a_2+a_5+a_8+a_{10} = \frac{s}{3}$
3. $a_4+a_{6}+a_{9}+a_{11} = \frac{s}{3}$

For this, I found many solutions. Some examples are:

$$  \begin{pmatrix}
8 & 5 & 19 & 25 \\
41 & 13 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 9 & 16 & 29 
\end{pmatrix}$$

And many more. I did it by first solving the linear equations (which got me $6$ free variables). Then, I started checking all possible entries for these free variables (limited them by 30, to keep numbers not too large). The other $6$ numbers were calculated accordingly.

The following general solution was used:

[image: General solution for simpler version]

It took some time, but I was able to come along with many solutions for this which worked as fine examples.

Yet now, if I wish to check for my newer version of the problem (with only $2$ possible divisions for $4$ elements such that their sum is $\frac{s}{3}$), I will have $4$ bound variables and $8$ free ones, which is starting to get a bit too much for such a naive program as I wrote.

Here comes my question(s):

1. Are there any such possible solutions? I want my matrix do be divided by $2$ different division (each of $4$ elements), but no more divisions than that (Hence, all my previous examples fail). Am I looking for something which does not exist?
2. If it does exist, any better ideas for a computer program to approach this than my naive approach?

(Just a small remark to emphasize that all numbers are to be non-negative integers, only at most one of them can be $0$)

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Your equations seem to have nothing to do with matrix properties, yes?  You could just present them as $6$ equations in $12$ unknowns.  As such, it's just a standard problem in linear algebra, yes?  A grossly underdetermined problem...just at a glance it looks like we can set them all to $0$ except $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_{10}$ which we'll set to $\frac s3$.  We note that each of the six equations has exactly one of those.  Nothing special about that solution, I'm sure there are plenty of others.

Comment: I edited a bit. I can allow one of them to be zero, but not more. I think the main part is not to create a matrix that will be divideable by these 2 ways (Way A: by rows, way B: as in the picture), but rather to make sure there is no other possible division (where each set in the division consists of $4$ elements). I know its simply a set of linear equations (and some of them with $\neq$), but from some reason I can't find such, so I was wondering if some of my requirements contradict themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, I found
$$a_{{1}}=47,a_{{2}}=11,a_{{3}}=100,a_{{4}}=113,a_{{5}}=155,a_{{6}}=23,
a_{{7}}=41,a_{{8}}=52,a_{{9}}=58,a_{{10}}=67,a_{{11}}=81,a_{{12}}=65
$$

My Maple program was as follows:

```
s:= add(a[i],i=1..12):
good:= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 9}, {3, 6, 10, 11}, {4, 7, 8, 12}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}:
eqs:= map(t -> add(a[i],i=t)=s/3, good);
bad:= combinat:-choose({$1..12},4) minus good:
S:=solve(eqs);  # this solves your equations
Free:= indets(map(rhs,S)); # these are the free variables in the solution
SS:= select(t -> rhs(t) <> lhs(t), S): # these are the equations for non-free variables
bads:= map(t -> subs(SS,add(a[i],i=t) - s/3), bad): 
     # these are the quantities you don't want 0 
for iter from 1 do
  FV:= [seq(Free[i]=rand(1..100)(),i=1..8)]; # random values for the free variables
  SV:= subs(FV,SS); # values for the other variables
  if min(map(rhs,SV)) >= 0 # check all variables nonnegative
     and not member(0, subs(FV,bads)) # check no other 4-tuple works
  then break
  fi
od:
printf("Success at iteration %d\n",iter):
sort([op(FV), op(SV)],(s,t) -> op(1,lhs(s))<op(1,lhs(t)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very helpful. Somewhat surprisingly, when I gave it a smaller interval (1..30 instead of 1..100) it ran slower - it required 1240 iterations whereas for 1..100 it required only 17.